# Find the minimum move between 2 list using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, zip

Given `a=[123,45]` and `b=[232,64]` we need to determine moves from `a` to `b`

`a[0]` to `b[0]` leads to:

```
increment by 1(1 to 2), 
increment by 1(2 to 3), 
decrement by 1(3 to 2)
```

so `3` move in total `(1+1+1)`.

`a[1]` to `b[1]` leads to

```
increment by 2(4 to 6), 
decrement by 1(5 to 4)
```

`3` move in total `(2 + 1)`

Min moves = `3 + 3` = `6`.

So for given 2 list we need to find the total moves to reach next list?

My program which is wrong is below

```
def sub(a,b):
 s = 0
 for x, y in zip(a,b):
   s += x-y
 return s
sub([123,45],[232,64])

-128
```

Comment: What kind of result are u expecting? Please provide a detailed explanation.

Comment: edited the result. find the total moves

Comment: @Maws I've edited my answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
def sub(a,b):
    s = 0
    for x, y in zip(a,b):
        s += sum(abs(int(n) - int(m)) for n, m in zip(str(x), str(y)))
    return s

print(sub([123,45],[232,64]))
```

Output:

```
6
```

Comment: could you please explain? I don't understand.